# Mac nodejs public directory permissions 'Forbidden'

Tags: macos, node.js, permissions

I'm using nodejs w/ expressjs on a Mac and the static files (css/js/img) for the client side, always show as 'Forbidden'.

I've tried setting chown on these directories to 777 and running node using sudo, but still it's showing Forbidden.

Any idea how to set proper permissions for a nodejs web server on a Mac?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm very curious: Is there a way to see the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing something like this

```
app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

in your app.configure?

Comment: Yeah, I have app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public")); but have tried with explicitly saying "/public" as well.

Comment: Are you trying localhost or browsing through a remote url?

Answer (score 5):

I am also developing node.js on Mac. Here is what I found will work:

```
app.use(express.static(require('path').resolve(__dirname + "/../../public")));
```

When serving the content, you must use:

```
res.sendfile(require('path').resolve(__dirname + "/../../public/some_content.html"));
```

I found the solution on this page:

https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/issues/298

Answer (score 0):

Not to be pedant, but have you tried chown or chmod?

Comment: Try chmod -R 777 public    ( Please do give us the result of $ ls -al in public, after that)